# how to create small notification application using event and delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling

I am planning to create a small demo application for notification. here, I have two users "User1" and "User2", they register to recieve notification.
I want to provide a time at which user gets the notification.

So, my question is, how can I pass the time for each subscriber and raise the Notify event at that time so the each subscriber get notified?

Please refer the blow code.

```
namespace ConceptDemos
{

public class Notifier
{
    public delegate void NotificationHandler();

    public event NotificationHandler Notify;

    public Notifier()


    {

    }

    public void OnNotify()
    {
        if (this.Notify != null)
        {
            Notify();
        }
    }

}

public class User1
{
    public void WakeMeUp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ringing User1's Alarm");
    }
}

public class User2
{
    public void StartMyTV()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting User2's TV");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Notifier Notifier = new Notifier();
        User1 oUser1 = new User1();
        Notifier.Notify += oUser1.WakeMeUp;
        User2 oUser2 = new User2();
        Notifier.Notify += oUser2.StartMyTV;

        Notifier.OnNotify();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to specify the time that `Notifier.OnNotify();` gets called?

Comment: yes, I want to specify time at which the Notification fire off and subscriber gets notified but time can be different for each user, like user1 says "please Wake me up at 7:00 AM" and User2 says "Please start my tv at 12:00 PM"

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you want to have a timer fire off a delegate on `User1` and `User2`. That can be done in a few different ways. One way that I have done it, is using a custom Timer class that supports synchronous and asynchronous callbacks.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/// <summary>
/// The Timer provides a means to start a timer with a callback that can be repeated over a set interval.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">A generic Type</typeparam>
public sealed class Timer<T> : CancellationTokenSource, IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The timer task
    /// </summary>
    private Task timerTask;

    /// <summary>
    /// How many times we have fired the timer thus far.
    /// </summary>
    private long fireCount = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Timer{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="callback">The callback.</param>
    /// <param name="state">The state.</param>
    public Timer(T state)
    {
        this.StateData = state;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the state data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The state data.
    /// </value>
    public T StateData { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the engine timer is currently running.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// <c>true</c> if this instance is running; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the specified start delay.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startDelay">The start delay in milliseconds.</param>
    /// <param name="interval">The interval in milliseconds.</param>
    /// <param name="numberOfFires">Specifies the number of times to invoke the timer callback when the interval is reached. Set to 0 for infinite.</param>
    public void Start(double startDelay, double interval, int numberOfFires, Action<T, Timer<T>> callback)
    {
        this.IsRunning = true;

        this.timerTask = Task
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(startDelay), this.Token)
            .ContinueWith(
                (task, state) => RunTimer(task, (Tuple<Action<T, EngineTimer<T>>, T>)state, interval, numberOfFires),
                Tuple.Create(callback, this.StateData),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the specified start delay.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startDelay">The start delay in milliseconds.</param>
    /// <param name="interval">The interval in milliseconds.</param>
    /// <param name="numberOfFires">Specifies the number of times to invoke the timer callback when the interval is reached. Set to 0 for infinite.</param>
    public void StartAsync(double startDelay, double interval, int numberOfFires, Func<T, Timer<T>, Task> callback)
    {
        this.IsRunning = true;

        this.timerTask = Task
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(startDelay), this.Token)
            .ContinueWith(
                async (task, state) => await RunTimerAsync(task, (Tuple<Func<T, Timer<T>, Task>, T>)state, interval, numberOfFires),
                Tuple.Create(callback, this.StateData),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the timer for this instance. It is not 
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        if (!this.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            this.Cancel();
        } 
        this.IsRunning = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cancels the timer and releases the unmanaged resources used by the <see cref="T:System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource" /> class and optionally releases the managed resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true to release both managed and unmanaged resources; false to release only unmanaged resources.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.IsRunning = false;
            this.Cancel();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private async Task RunTimer(Task task, Tuple<Action<T, EngineTimer<T>>, T> state, double interval, int numberOfFires)
    {
        while (!this.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Only increment if we are supposed to.
            if (numberOfFires > 0)
            {
                this.fireCount++;
            }

            state.Item1(state.Item2, this);
            await PerformTimerCancellationCheck(interval, numberOfFires);
        }
    }

    private async Task RunTimerAsync(Task task, Tuple<Func<T, EngineTimer<T>, Task>, T> state, double interval, int numberOfFires)
    {
        while (!this.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Only increment if we are supposed to.
            if (numberOfFires > 0)
            {
                this.fireCount++;
            }

            await state.Item1(state.Item2, this);
            await PerformTimerCancellationCheck(interval, numberOfFires);
        }
    }

    private async Task PerformTimerCancellationCheck(double interval, int numberOfFires)
    {
        // If we have reached our fire count, stop. If set to 0 then we fire until manually stopped.
        if (numberOfFires > 0 && this.fireCount >= numberOfFires)
        {
            this.Stop();
        }

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(interval), this.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Now you can wire up something like this:

```
// Create a new user and timer
User1 oUser1 = new User1();
var timer = new Timer(oUser1);

// Set the time to notify the user to 5 minutes from now.
var timeToNotify = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
new TimeSpan(timeToNotify.Hour, timeToNotify.Minute, timeToNotify.Second);

// Star the timer. In 5 minutes it will invoke the WakeMeUp() method.
timer.Start(
    startDelay: timeToNotify, 
    interval: 0, 
    numberOfFires: 1,
    callback: (user, timer) => user.WakeMeUp());
```

If you are instead, wanting to have some kind of observer pattern, let me know. There is a better way to go about notifying the user that an event has happened and the user needs to react to it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the Pub/Sub pattern. With this pattern, you can have each `User` instance subscribe to a specific publication message that the publisher can send out.

An example of this usage would be like this:

#### User1 class

```
public class User1 : IDispose
{
    private ISubscription subscription;
    public User1(NotificationManager notificationManager)
    {
        this.subscription = notificationManager.Subscribe<WakeUpNotification>(
            (notification, subscription) => this.WakeMeUp());
    }

    public void WakeMeUp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ringing User1's Alarm");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.subscription.Unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

#### User2 class

```
public class User2 : IDispose
{
    private ISubscription subscription;
    public User2(NotificationManager notificationManager)
    {
        this.subscription = notificationManager.Subscribe<StartMyTvNotification>(
            (notification, subscription) => this.StartMyTv());
    }

    public void StartMyTv()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ringing User1's Alarm");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.subscription.Unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

#### App class somewhere

```
var notificationManager = new NotificationManager();
var user1 = new User1(notificationManager);
var user2 = new User2(notificationManager);

notificationManager.Publish(new WakeUpNotification(true));
notificationManager.Publish(new TurnOnMyTvNotification(DateTime.Now));
user1.Dispose();
```

This can be coupled with a timer, that allows for publishing the messages at different intervals. You can use a Timer to publish `WakeUpNotification` at a different time than when `TurnOnMyTvNotification` is published.

## Pub/Sub implementation

The following is the implementation of a publish/subscribe setup. The code is pretty well documented.

#### INotificationCenter

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a contract for Mediators to use when handling notifications between objects.
/// </summary>
public interface INotificationCenter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets up a new handler and returns it for subscription set up.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TMessageType">An IMessage implementation that the given handler will be provided when messages are dispatched</typeparam>
    /// <param name="handler">The handler used to process incoming messages.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns an ISubscription that can be used to unsubscribe.</returns>
    ISubscription Subscribe<TMessageType>(Action<TMessageType, ISubscription> callback, Func<TMessageType, bool> condition = null) where TMessageType : class, IMessage;

    /// <summary>
    /// Publishes the specified message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TMessageType"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    void Publish<TMessageType>(TMessageType message) where TMessageType : class, IMessage;
}
```

#### NotificationManager

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// The mediator for all messaging
/// </summary>
public class NotificationManager : INotificationCenter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of subscribed listeners
    /// </summary>
    private ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<ISubscription>> listeners =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<ISubscription>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribe publications for the message type specified.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TMessageType">A concrete implementation of IMessage</typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ISubscription Subscribe<TMessageType>(Action<TMessageType, ISubscription> callback, Func<TMessageType, bool> condition = null) where TMessageType : class, IMessage
    {
        ExceptionFactory.ThrowIf(
            callback == null,
            () => new ArgumentNullException(nameof(callback), "Callback must not be null when subscribing"));

        Type messageType = typeof(TMessageType);

        // Create our key if it doesn't exist along with an empty collection as the value.
        if (!listeners.ContainsKey(messageType))
        {
            listeners.TryAdd(messageType, new List<ISubscription>());
        }

        // Add our notification to our listener collection so we can publish to it later, then return it.
        // TODO: Move instancing the Notification in to a Factory.
        var handler = new Notification<TMessageType>();
        handler.Register(callback, condition);
        handler.Unsubscribing += this.Unsubscribe;

        List<ISubscription> subscribers = listeners[messageType];
        lock (subscribers)
        {
            subscribers.Add(handler);
        }

        return handler;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Publishes the specified message to all subscribers
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    public void Publish<T>(T message) where T : class, IMessage
    {
        ExceptionFactory.ThrowIf(
            message == null,
            () => new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message), "You can not publish a null message."));

        if (!listeners.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (INotification<T> handler in listeners[typeof(T)])
        {
            handler.ProcessMessage(message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unsubscribes the specified handler by removing their handler from our collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The message Type you want to unsubscribe from</typeparam>
    /// <param name="subscription">The subscription to unsubscribe.</param>
    private void Unsubscribe(NotificationArgs args)
    {
        // If the key doesn't exist or has an empty collection we just return.
        // We will leave the key in there for future subscriptions to use.
        if (!listeners.ContainsKey(args.MessageType) || listeners[args.MessageType].Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Remove the subscription from the collection associated with the key.
        List<ISubscription> subscribers = listeners[args.MessageType];
        lock (subscribers)
        {
            subscribers.Remove(args.Subscription);
        }

        args.Subscription.Unsubscribing -= this.Unsubscribe;
    }
}
```

#### ISubscription

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a contract to Types wanting to subscribe to published messages 
/// with conditions and a callback.
/// </summary>
public interface ISubscription
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the subscription is being unsubscribed.
    /// </summary>
    event Action<NotificationArgs> Unsubscribing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="ISubscription"/> is active.
    /// </summary>
    bool IsActive { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unsubscribes the registerd callbacks from receiving notifications.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="notificationCenter">The notification center.</param>
    void Unsubscribe();
}
```

#### INotification

```
using System;

/// <summary>
/// Processes a subscription message.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TMessageType">The type of the message type.</typeparam>
public interface INotification<TMessageType> : ISubscription where TMessageType : class, IMessage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the specified action for callback when a notification is fired for T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="callback">The message being posted along with the subscription registered to receive the post.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    void Register(
        Action<TMessageType, ISubscription> callback,
        Func<TMessageType, bool> condition = null);

    /// <summary>
    /// Processes the message, invoking the registered callbacks if their conditions are met.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    void ProcessMessage(TMessageType message);
}
```

#### IMessage

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows for receiving the content of a message
/// </summary>
public interface IMessage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns the content of the message</returns>
    object GetContent();
}

/// <summary>
/// Allows for receiving the content of a message
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TContent">The type of the content.</typeparam>
public interface IMessage<TContent> : IMessage where TContent : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content of the message.
    /// </summary>
    TContent Content { get; }
}
```

#### WakeMeUpNotification

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides methods for dispatching notifications to subscription handlers
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TMessageType">The type of the message type.</typeparam>
public class WakeMeUpNotification : IMessage<DateTime> where TContentType : class
{
    public WakeMeUpNotification(DateTime timeToWakeUp)
    {
        this.Content = timeToWakeUp
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content of the message.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Content { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content of the message.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime GetContent()
    {
        return this.Content;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content.
    /// </summary>
    object IMessage.GetContent()
    {
        return this.GetContent();
    }
}
```

#### StartMyTvNotification

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides methods for dispatching notifications to subscription handlers
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TMessageType">The type of the message type.</typeparam>
public class StartMyTvNotification : IMessage<bool> where TContentType : class
{
    public StartMyTvNotification(bool isOn)
    {
        this.Content = isOn;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content of the message.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Content { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content of the message.
    /// </summary>
    public bool GetContent()
    {
        return this.Content;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content.
    /// </summary>
    object IMessage.GetContent()
    {
        return this.GetContent();
    }
}
```

#### Notification

```
using System;

/// <summary>
/// Handles chat message subscriptions
/// </summary>
internal class Notification<TMessage> : INotification<TMessage> where TMessage : class, IMessage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The callbacks invoked when the handler processes the messages.
    /// </summary>
    private Action<TMessage, ISubscription> callback;

    /// <summary>
    /// The conditions that must be met in order to fire the callbacks.
    /// </summary>
    private Func<TMessage, bool> condition;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the subscription is being unsubscribed.
    /// </summary>
    public event Action<NotificationArgs> Unsubscribing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="ISubscription" /> is active.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsActive { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers a callback for when a chat message is published by the MessageCenter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="processor">The message.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void Register(
        Action<TMessage, ISubscription> processor,
        Func<TMessage, bool> condition)
    {
        this.callback = processor;
        this.condition = condition;
        this.IsActive = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unsubscribes the handler from notifications. This cleans up all of the callback references and conditions.
    /// </summary>
    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        this.callback = null;
        this.condition = null;

        try
        {
            this.OnUnsubscribing();
        }
        finally
        {
            this.IsActive = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Processes the message by verifying the callbacks can be invoked, then invoking them.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    public void ProcessMessage(TMessage message)
    {
        if (this.condition != null && !this.condition(message))
        {
            this.callback(message, this);
            return;
        }

        this.callback(message, this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the notification is being unsubscribed from.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void OnUnsubscribing()
    {
        var handler = this.Unsubscribing;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(new NotificationArgs(this, typeof(TMessage)));
    }
}
```

#### NotificationArgs

```
public class NotificationArgs
{
    public NotificationArgs(ISubscription subscription, Type messageType)
    {
        this.Subscription = subscription;
        this.MessageType = messageType;
    }

    public ISubscription Subscription { get; private set; }

    public Type MessageType { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I would put in to replace the `Notifier.OnNotify();` line:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.AutoReset = false;
timer.Interval =
    new DateTime(2015, 5, 22, 15, 6, 0)
        .Subtract(DateTime.Now)
        .TotalMilliseconds;

System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler handler = null;
handler = (s, e) =>
{
    Notifier.OnNotify();
    timer.Elapsed -= handler;
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Dispose();
};
timer.Elapsed += handler;

timer.Start();
```

Obviously you need to change the date to suit when you want the event to fire.

I have included a fairly complete example of how to fire an event and then **clean up afterwards**. You should always do this kind of clean up.

Now this will fire the event on a background thread. If you need to have the event fire on a UI thread then you need to do the appropriate invokes to get it there.

The only other comment I thought I would make is that your implementation of `OnNotify` is has a slight bug if you have any multi-threading. It should be like this:

```
public void OnNotify()
{
    var notify = this.Notify;
    if (notify != null)
    {
        notify();
    }
}
```

That stops the issue that the delegates in `this.Notify` get removed by another thread between the `if` and the invocation. It is a good idea to get into the habit of writing your code this way as a matter of good practice.